# Python access elements of a list of strings

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings as given below. I want to access each element.

```
str_list = ['a.b', 'b.c','c_a']
```

Expected output:

```
'a.b'
'b.c'
'c_a'
```

My code and present output:

```
for i in range(0,len(str_list)): 
   print(str_list[i])
a
.
b
```

How to get my desired output?

Comment: By the way, your posted code works fine

Comment: That's not the output of this code.